# How to connect hive with cloudera's hue?

Tags: hive, ubuntu-18.04, thrift, hue

I install cloudera's hue and start server.

but i got an error on website(127.0.0.1:8000/hue/editor/?type=hive) like below:

```
TSocket read 0 bytes (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('TSocket read 0 bytes',)
```

I checked the log and can see log like below:

```
QueryError: TSocket read 0 bytes (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('TSocket read 0 bytes',)
```

I use hiveserver2 and transportmode is binary.

How can i solve this problem??

**ADD**. I use NOSASL in hive-site.xml
**ADD**. My beeswax server setting like below:
{
"dialect": "beeswax",
"has_session_pool": False,
"server_name": "beeswax",
"transport_mode": "socket",
"auth_username": "hue",
"server_host": "localhost",
"server_port": 10000,
"use_sasl": True,
"auth_password_used": False,
"http_url": "http://localhost:10001/cliservice",
"max_number_of_sessions": 1,
"close_sessions": False,
"principal": None
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered myself.

As a result of continuous web surfing, I found a directory and file where hue could be set. In fact, I could find many articles asking me to modify hue's setting file before, but no one told me which directory the setting file exists in. Eventually, I found out the location of the setting file through an article, and after unannotating "use_sasl" in the setting file, I modified the NOSASL of save-site.xml to NONE. This worked well!